# Should I add s in questions that start with Could?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I'd like to ask a question like this, but I am not sure whether I should add s at the end of the verb

Could you tell me how long it usually takes to ... ?

or

Could you tell me how long does it usually take to ... ?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: @Clare - I don't mind if you gently nudge people toward showing more research, provided it's done in an [amiable and cordial way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback). However, I don't see much point in leaving comments like "What research have you done?" under questions that were asked months and months ago.

Answer (score 4):

1. **Direct** questions include the auxiliary.

   > *How long **does** it usually take to ...* ?
2. **Indirect** questions don't include the auxiliary.

   > *Could you tell me how long it usually **takes** to ...* ?

Comment: what if, say, "who did it?" :p

Comment: @HermanNz But *did* is not working as an auxiliary in that case. :)