# did wake up or woke up

Tags: american-english, slang, informal-language

I want to know which of the sentences below is used? I'm not talking about grammar, I'm talking about slang or daily talking with your friends or families.

> When did you wake up?

(which is grammatically correct)

or

> When you woke up?

Comment: I have never heard anyone use
`When you woke up?`

Comment: It's hard to say, as every situation is different. However I can for a certainty say that I've never heard anyone say "When you woke up?"...

Comment: [Related](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/83196/22098).

Comment: This is a good question, because in informal speech we do sometimes fail to restructure a sentence as a question.  For example, someone might say, "You bought those yesterday?" instead of "Did you buy those yesterday?"  But in standard English, "When you woke up?" sounds extremely wrong.  I think it might be normal in African-American Vernacular English, but I am going to let someone with more knowledge address that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely the first sentence.

> When did you wake up?

In the English mind, we would be expecting more to the sentence if you said, "When you woke up?"  The natural English speaker would be listening for the rest of your sentence... When I woke up, WHAT?!  When you woke up, did you have breakfast?  When you woke up, did you take a shower?